# Spin-flip of electrons in non-neutral hydrogen atoms in water and fat molecules

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

What is the Spin-flip of electrons in non-neutral hydrogen atoms in water and fat molecules?
I know there is known spin-flip RF of electrons in neutral hydrogen atoms (hydrogen line).

Thanks,
Cheers